# Android studio getting freez during layout design

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

I have Following PC Configuration:

- 8GB RAM
- intel-i5 Processor

when i designing the layout in android studio it's working fine for 2 or 3 complex layout design.

but after that studio start getting freez and slowdown the PC performance.

Also when i restart the android studio then again its work fine for 2 or 3 layout design.

so, I can not understand the exact reason why this happen?

Comment: How many views are in that layout?

Comment: near about  >40 view in one layout.

Comment: Its not advisable to have so many views in one layout. You're cause the garbage collector to be called too many times if you were to run the view on an actual device. Can't you recycle them?

Answer (score 1):

It maybe due to large cache files that are built up in your Disk Storage.
There are lots of ways you can improve the performance of Android Studio

Here is a link that lays out the practices for improvement of gradle build time

> http://www.universalmind.com/blog/10-tips-to-improve-your-gradle-build-time/

Comment: i will try ur solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things which you need to try:

1. Clear your PC cache and temp files.
2. Just rebuild android project.

Comment: you are right..but did't work.. I clean every cache and temp file from PC every morning when i start my work.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting too many views in your layout. Android has a [limit of 80 views per layout](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-tools-layout-optimization--mobile-5245). And you have more than 80 (From the comments you said you had 40 views) in total. You should recycle some of them or maybe use a listview or a recycler view to [optimize](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) you layout